# Question regarding the fullness of restriction functor of ${\rm Sh}(X) \to {\rm Sh}(\mathcal{B})$

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I am trying to prove that the restriction functor $\mathbb{r}: {\rm Sh}(X) \to {\rm Sh}(\mathcal{B})$ is an equivalence of categories, and I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560073/for-basis-mathcalb-of-the-topology-on-x-the-restriction-functor-mathbf) (here you can also find the full statement that I am trying to solve, also here is a [question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852818/question-regarding-the-restriction-functor-of-rm-shx-to-rm-sh-mathcal) also related to this problem).

However, my question is now a bit different: we wish to prove that $f'$ is a morphism of sheaves (you can see what this means more clearly in the answer I have linked). I did as they hinted and considered a $U' \subseteq U$, $x \in F(U)$, and again a open covering of $U$ by $\{V_i| i\in I\} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$. I have reached thus far:
$$
(f'(U)(x){\mid_{U'}}){\mid_{V_i}}=(f'(U')(x{\mid_{U'}})){\mid_{V_i}}=f'(V_i)(x{\mid_{V_i}})=y_i
$$

Now, by the injectivity condition part on $G$ (I think, given that we previously found that $y_i{\mid_{U_i \cap U_j}}=y_j{\mid_{U_i \cap U_j}}$), we have that
$$
f'(U_i)(x){\mid_{U_i \cap U_j}}= f'(U_j)(x){\mid_{U_i \cap U_j}}
$$

If I am wrong please correct me on this.

Is this enough to prove that $f'$ is a morphism of sheaves? And do you have any tips to prove that $\mathbb{r}(f')=f?$

Any help is really, really appreciated! Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

Comment: By "injectivity part of the sheaf condition on $G$" I meant what other sources might call "separatedness of $G$": if you have a cover $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$ of $U'$, and two sections $y_1, y_2 \in G(U')$, then $(y_1) |_{V_i} = (y_2) |_{V_i}$ for each $i \in I$ implies $y_1 = y_2$.  Now, try applying this for $y_1 = (f'(U)(x))|_{U'}$ and $y_2 = f'(U')(x |_{U'})$ with the canonical cover $\{ V\in \mathcal{B} \mid V \subseteq U' \}$.

Comment: As for showing $r(f') = f$: by construction, whenever $U$ is open and $V \subseteq U$, $V \in \mathcal{B}$, then for any section $x \in F(U)$, you have $(f'(U)(x)) |_V = f(V)(x |_V)$.  Now, if $U \in \mathcal{B}$ already, try the case $V = U$...